# Looping through an array and placing something every somewhat steps into an array

Tags: arrays, vb.net, string, algorithm

So I have been busy working on an assignment lately, now I'm programming in Visual Basic, Using Visual Studio 2013 Update 4, and I'm working in the .NET Framework.

Here's my problem/question:
What I want to accomplish is that I run through an array of 81 (length) consisting of only characters. I want to iterate through this array and after 9 steps of my for-loop I want to save those 9 characters into a string.

With this I mean I want to save characters 0-8 in a string, then 9-17 in another string, and so on…

(Array will be filled in my program)

```
Dim charactersArray(81) as character

For intIndex as integer = 0 to 81
'Add 9 characters into a string
Next
```

I have tried a-lot to accomplish this but have failed to find a solution yet, I have searched all over the internet but I couldn't find a solution.
So hopefully anybody here can help me out. :D

*(Pretty much I'm asking you to make a little algorithm for me :/ )*

Comment: You probably want to use one of the string constructors which will take a 'character array' and return a string: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131424(v=vs.110).aspx - sorry I don't have the time to tap out sample code, perhaps someone else can build upon this with an answer. GL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This prints to console instead of adding items to something like an ArrayList, it also fixes the off-by-one bug in the original `For` Loop:

```
Dim charactersArray(81) as character
For intIndex as integer = 0 to 80 Step 9
    Dim s = New String(charactersArray, intIndex, 9)
    System.Console.WriteLine(s)
Next
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
This is more or less exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

There are three possibilities that comes to mind.

The first one is a classical approach that builds a string one character at time until you have read 9 characters, then restart for the next 9 character until you reach the end of the array.

The trick here is the [MOD operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se0w9esz.aspx) to discover when you have read 9 characters (Notice that I start from one to avoid the first 0 MOD 9 that returns 0)

```
Dim sb = new StringBuilder()
For intIndex as integer = 1 to 81
    if intIndex Mod 9 = 0 then
        sb.Append(charactersArray(intIndex - 1))
        Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString())
        sb.Clear()
    else
        sb.Append(charactersArray(intIndex - 1))
    End if
Next
```

The other approach uses Linq and is a lot more readable

```
Dim index = 0
Do while(index < 81)
    Dim s = new String(charactersArray.Skip(index).Take(9).ToArray())
    Console.WriteLine(s)
    index += 9
Loop
```

Here I build a new string skipping the characters already read and build a new string using the next 9 characters

A third approach is using the Array.Copy method

```
Dim charBuffer(8) as Char
Dim index = 0
Do while(index < 81)
    Array.Copy(charactersArray, index, charBuffer, 0, 9)
    Console.WriteLine(new string(charBuffer))
    index += 9
Loop
```

The performance of the three methods in a loop of 100000 iterations are the following (take it with a lot of prudence and test on your hardware)

```
StringBuilder:66 ms
Linq:706 ms
Array.Copy:40 ms
```

Comment: Thank You Very Much for your answer. It has learned me a lot and I now know how to implement this into my code. Although the answer posted a little later is more fitting to my exact question ;)